# Applying Reflexivity of String Equivalence in Agda Proofs

Tags: string, equality, agda, decidable

In my Agda program, I have a small function that checks for string equality (simplified for example):

```
open import Data.String.Base using (String)
open import Date.String.Properties using (_≈?_)
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable using (does)

foo : String → String → String
foo a b = if (does (a ≈? b))
          then "Hello"
          else "Bye"
```

Later in my program, I want to prove something that involves `foo`. In particular, `foo` is applied to two equal strings and thus I want to show that `does (a ≈? a)` evaluates to `true` and thus `foo` returns `"Hello"`. So as an intermediate step, I want to prove the reflexivity of `foo`:

```
foo-refl : ∀ {a : String} → true ≡ does (a ≈? a)
foo-refl = ?
```

However, I fail to prove it. When exploring the standard library I see different ways for equality of strings (`_≟_`, `_≈?_`, `_≈_`).
Also, I saw proofs for reflexivity for some of these equivalence relations in the standard library, for example `Data.String.Properties.≈-refl`, but I fail to apply them to prove my theorem above.

So my questions are:

1. Am I using the right/convential kind of equality-check for strings?
2. How to prove my theorem? I guess it is already proven in the standard library but I fail to see it.

### Edit

Thanks to @gallai's answer below, I came up with the following solution:

**TL;DR**: Use `_==_` from `Data.String.Properties` to check equality of strings at runtime.

**Long version**:

```
open import Data.Bool using (Bool; true; if_then_else_)
open import Data.String.Base using (String)
open import Data.String.Properties using (_≟_; _==_)
open import Relation.Binary.Definitions using (Decidable)
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable using (yes; isYes)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_; refl; cong; ≡-≟-identity)

≟-refl : ∀ {S : String} → (S ≟ S) ≡ yes refl
≟-refl = ≡-≟-identity _≟_ refl

==-refl : ∀ {S : String} → (S == S) ≡ true
==-refl {S} = cong isYes (≟-refl {S})

-- And then use == in the definition of foo.
foo : String → String → String
foo a b = if (a == b)
          then "Hello"
          else "Bye"
```

To check that I can now make proofs on `foo`, I tried the following:

```
_ : "Hello" ≡ foo "gallais" "gallais"
_ = refl
```

realizing that the proofs of `≟-refl` and `==-refl` are superfluous. So one can just use `_==_` to compare strings during runtime. This was not (and still is not really) clear to me when facing at least five different definitions of string equality in the standard library: `_≟_`, `_≈?_`, `_≈_`, `_==_`, `primStringEquality`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic proof defined in [`Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.html):

```
module _ (_≟_ : DecidableEquality A) {x y : A} where
  ≡-≟-identity : (eq : x ≡ y) → x ≟ y ≡ yes eq
```